# extracting needed items from an array

Tags: php, filtering

if I have an array structured like:

```
[0] => bad
[1] => good
[2] => bad
[3] => bad
[4] => good
[5] => bad
[6] => bad
[7] => good
[8] => bad
[9] => bad
[10] => good
[11] => bad
```

And i need an array with only good items like:

```
[0] => good
[1] => good
[2] => good
[3] => good
[4] => good
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Did you mean to re-number the entries in your sample output?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) function :

```
$good_value ="good";
$new_array = array_filter($old_array,function($value)use($good_value){
                                 return $value === $good_value;
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an approach that utilizes [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
$goodArray = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    if $value = "good" {
        array_push($goodArray, $value);
    }
}
```

or if you want to maintain the original indices:

```
$goodArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value = "good") {
        $goodArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a loop

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($oldArray as $value) {
  if($value == 'good')
    $newArray[] = $value
}
```

of if you need to retain the keys

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($oldArray as $key=>$value) {
  if($value == 'good')
    $newArray[$key] = $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

```
function good($var)
{
    return($var == "good");
}
$ary = array_filter($ary, "good");
print_r($ary);
```

If you need to re-index the array, just add this:

```
$ary = array_values($ary);
```

**[CodePad example](http://codepad.org/9vUks3J9)**